# Need sql query to display row numbers in table

Tags: numbers, rom

I need sql query to display row numbers in table. I am working in Mainframes and we use SQL queries to connect to oracle tables . I need a query to display row numbers in a table , table doesnt have a column for row numbers . In Mainframes we can input sql queries alone . Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Post what you've already tried :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROWNUM](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) *Pseudocolumn*.

**Example**

```
SELECT ROWNUM,a.* FROM employees a;
```